How to make the toggle switch show/hide an array object?
I am trying to show/hide the description when I toggle the switch. I also want the switch to be checked at first. When The switch is checked, the description of each result should show. each result have their own description.
My code doesn't do any of that. Instead, all of the descriptions are showing for each result. The toggle switch is not showing the descriptions but it is hiding them.


// imports

const results = [...]

const upvoteSVG = '...';

const downvoteSVG = '...';

export default function SearchResults() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0); 
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(Array.isArray(results) ? results.map(result => result.description) : []);

    const List = () => {
        return (
            <>
            {
                results.slice(page * 10, page * 10 + 10).map((result) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="bg-gray-800 shadow-lg shadow-red-500 m-5">
                            <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 p-5">
                                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-4">
                                        <p className="text-lg font-bold">{result.name}</p>
                                        <p className="text-blue-500"><Link href={result.url}>Website</Link></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>{result.categories.slice(0, 3).join(", ")}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap w-1/2">
                                    <p>{description}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex flex-row bottom-0 gap-4 bg-gray-900 justify-items-end justify-end pr-2">
                                <p>{result.upvotes}<button className="rounded-full bg-red-500 w-fit h-fit p-2 m-2"><Image src="upvote.svg" alt="upvote" width={20} height={20}/></button></p>
                                <p>{result.downvotes} <button className="rounded-full bg-red-500 w-fit h-fit p-2 m-2"><Image src="downvote.svg" alt="downvote" width={20} height={20}/></button></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
            </>
        )
    }

    const prevPage = () => {...}

    const nextPage = () => {...}

    const showDescription = () => {
        description ? setDescription([]) : setDescription(results.map(result => result.description));
    }

    const PaginationNumbers = () => {...}

    const NOP = () => {...}

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <div>
                <Search/>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
                <div className="w-1/2">
                    <List/>
                </div>
                <div className="w-1/2 m-2 p-2 flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-gray-800">
                    <label className="inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="" className="sr-only peer" id="toggle" onChange={showDescription}/>
                        <span className="ms-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 m-2">Show Description</span>
                        <div className="relative w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-red-500 dark:peer-focus:ring-red-800 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full rtl:peer-checked:after:-translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:start-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-red-600" ></div> 
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center flex-wrap w-1/2">
                <button onClick={prevPage} className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg">Prev</button>
                <PaginationNumbers/>
                <button onClick={nextPage} className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}




Consider converting:
const [description, setDescription] = useState(Array.isArray(results) ? results.map(result => result.description) : []);

To a boolean flag like:
const [showDescriptions, setShowDescription] = useState(false);

This simplifies the state and it will have less dependencies.
Then, use this showDescriptions in List to conditionally show the descriptions:
{showDescriptions && (
  <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap w-1/2">
    <p>{result.description}</p>
  </div>
)}

Update showDescription() to match this new format:
const showDescription = () => setShowDescription(value => !value);



const { useState } = React;

const Search = () => 'Search';
const Link = (...props) => <a {...props}/>;
const Image = (...props) => <img {...props}/>;

const results = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    url: '',
    categories: ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    description: 'Foo description',
    upvotes: 5,
    downvotes: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    url: '',
    categories: ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    description: 'Foo description',
    upvotes: 5,
    downvotes: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    url: '',
    categories: ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    description: 'Foo description',
    upvotes: 5,
    downvotes: 5,
  }
];

const upvoteSVG = '...';

const downvoteSVG = '...';

function SearchResults() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [showDescriptions, setShowDescription] = useState(false);

  const List = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {results.slice(page * 10, page * 10 + 10).map((result) => {
          return (
            <div className="bg-gray-800 shadow-lg shadow-red-500 m-5">
              <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 p-5">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                  <div className="flex flex-row gap-4">
                    <p className="text-lg font-bold">{result.name}</p>
                    <p className="text-blue-500">
                      <Link href={result.url}>Website</Link>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <p>{result.categories.slice(0, 3).join(', ')}</p>
                </div>
                {showDescriptions && (
                  <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap w-1/2">
                    <p>{result.description}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-row bottom-0 gap-4 bg-gray-900 justify-items-end justify-end pr-2">
                <p>
                  {result.upvotes}
                  <button className="rounded-full bg-red-500 w-fit h-fit p-2 m-2">
                    <Image
                      src="upvote.svg"
                      alt="upvote"
                      width={20}
                      height={20}
                    />
                  </button>
                </p>
                <p>
                  {result.downvotes}{' '}
                  <button className="rounded-full bg-red-500 w-fit h-fit p-2 m-2">
                    <Image
                      src="downvote.svg"
                      alt="downvote"
                      width={20}
                      height={20}
                    />
                  </button>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  const prevPage = () => {};

  const nextPage = () => {};

  const showDescription = () => setShowDescription(value => !value);

  const PaginationNumbers = () => {};

  const NOP = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div>
        <Search />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
        <div className="w-1/2">
          <List />
        </div>
        <div className="w-1/2 m-2 p-2 flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-gray-800">
          <label className="inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value=""
              className="sr-only peer"
              id="toggle"
              onChange={showDescription}
            />
            <span className="ms-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 m-2">
              Show Description
            </span>
            <div className="relative w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-red-500 dark:peer-focus:ring-red-800 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full rtl:peer-checked:after:-translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:start-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-red-600"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center flex-wrap w-1/2">
        <button
          onClick={prevPage}
          className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg"
        >
          Prev
        </button>
        <PaginationNumbers />
        <button
          onClick={nextPage}
          className="bg-gray-800 text-white m-2 p-2 hover:bg-white hover:text-black rounded-lg"
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<SearchResults />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



